# Querying SCCM only works sometimes Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, sccm

I wish to query the SCCM SQL server but it only works when the command is a certain way. For instance, this works

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace $SCCMNameSpace -computer $SCCMServer -query "select Name from sms_r_system"
```

But this will not work

```
(Get-WmiObject -namespace $SCCMNameSpace -computer $SCCMServer -query "select Name from sms_r_system").Name
```

When I run the first command, the output looks like this for every system

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : SMS_R_System
__SUPERCLASS     : SMS_Resource
__DYNASTY        : SMS_BaseClass
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {SMS_Resource, SMS_BaseClass}
__SERVER         : serverName
__NAMESPACE      : root\sms\site_P01
__PATH           : 
Name             : computerName
PSComputerName   : serverName
```

I tried surrounding the command with parenthesis in the non-working example and doing `.Name` to retrieve the "Name" attribute but that didn't work. There was no error but the script just kept running with no output.

Why is this the case? I'm able to run a command like this without a problem:

```
$Computers =(Get-WmiObject -namespace $SCCMNameSpace -computer $SCCMServer -query "select Name from sms_r_system where LastLogonUserName='$User'").Name
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 5.1

Comment: Instead of forming your own query, have you considered using  the cmdlet's parameters?  `Get-WmiObject -Namespace $SCCMNameSpace -ComputerName $SCCMServer -Class SMS_R_SYSTEM -Property Name`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I had not considered that; however, that is yielding the exact same output instead of just the name.

Comment: Are you able to access the name on it then?  `$output['Name']`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It won't even let me do `$output = Get-WmiObject -Namespace $SCCMNameSpace -ComputerName $SCCMServer -Class SMS_R_SYSTEM -Property Name`, it causes the script to never end

Comment: Is your `$SCCMServer` responding to requests?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, it responds to ping requests, I can run some commands, I'm just trying to learn how to correctly specify queries without using the Powershell cmdlet `ConfigurationManager.psd1` since it's not really an option for my circumstance

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It works when I do `Get-WmiObject -Namespace $SCCMNameSpace -ComputerName $SCCMServer -Class SMS_R_SYSTEM | select -Property Name` but I can't it in a variable like `$computers = Get-WmiObject -Namespace $SCCMNameSpace -ComputerName $SCCMServer -Class SMS_R_SYSTEM | select -Property Name`

Comment: That is incredibly bizarre and sounds like an environment problem.  Can you use `Tee-Object -Variable output`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Like this? `$output;
    Get-WmiObject -Namespace $SCCMNameSpace -ComputerName $SCCMServer -Class SMS_R_SYSTEM | Tee-Object -Variable output | select -Property Name` It runs, only displaying the names

Comment: Does the output exist in the `$output` variable now?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes it does

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Any idea why powershell is being so weird?

Comment: Are you running your commands in a PowerShell window? Or some kind of editor environment?  I haven't heard of problems like these before.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm just using PowerShell ISE

Comment: that's probably your problem.  try running it in a console window (`powershell.exe`) instead of the ISE (`powershell_ise.exe`)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 No dice. I replaced the variables with their hard-coded equivalents and ran it in regular powershell and it's still stumped